# Choose Pandas dataframe index after which data in a column is all higher than a specific value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison

I have a dataframe in pandas, something like:

```
df.head()
                             P1'S1       P1'S2       P1'S3       P1'S4  
Year_Day_Hour_Min_Sec.                                                   
2005-01-20 00:01:00      10.292887    5.849372    5.154812    5.824268   
2005-01-20 00:02:00     423.334728  415.878661  346.619247  333.317992   
2005-01-20 00:03:00     340.753138  429.447699  370.945607  417.832636   
2005-01-20 00:04:00     494.067643  426.577406  332.811715  361.725941   
2005-01-20 00:05:00     415.266039  396.711994  370.289749  398.025802
```

And I want to get the index at which time **all values** starting from that index are higher than `400` in the `P1'S1` column. So, in this case the correct answer would be index `2005-01-20 00:04:00`

What's an efficient way to do this? Preferably one that can be used with any kind of comparison condition.

Comment: IIUC then `df.iloc[df.index.get_loc(df[df["P1'S1"] > 400].index[0]):]` should work

Comment: That will give me the 1st index after which **one** value higher than `400` appears in `P1'S1` I need the 1st index after which **all** values in `P1'S1` are higher than 400.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little indirect, but if we take the cumulative minimum of the reversed column, we'll know the lowest value seen at or beyond that point.  The first value of *that* which is > 400 is the location you're looking for:

```
>>> ((df["P1'S1"].iloc[::-1].cummin().iloc[::-1]) > 400).idxmax()
'2005-01-20 00:04:00'
```

Basically, once we get to

```
>>> df["P1'S1"].iloc[::-1].cummin().iloc[::-1]
Year_Day_Hour_Min_Sec.
2005-01-20 00:01:00     10.292887
2005-01-20 00:02:00    340.753138
2005-01-20 00:03:00    340.753138
2005-01-20 00:04:00    415.266039
2005-01-20 00:05:00    415.266039
Name: P1'S1, dtype: float64
```

We can use the fact that `idxmax` returns the first index which hits the maximum value to turn

```
>>> (df["P1'S1"].iloc[::-1].cummin().iloc[::-1] > 400)
Year_Day_Hour_Min_Sec.
2005-01-20 00:01:00    False
2005-01-20 00:02:00    False
2005-01-20 00:03:00    False
2005-01-20 00:04:00     True
2005-01-20 00:05:00     True
Name: P1'S1, dtype: bool
```

into `2005-01-20 00:04:00`.

Note that I'm assuming we have unique indices here.  We could work around that but I haven't had my coffee yet. :-)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. It's an elegant solution even if it only works to choose a value greater than `x` and not some other condition.